# Unable to edit user settings when trying to install BASH into VSCode. "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",

Tags: javascript, json, bash, typescript, git-bash

it's 808 back again with another question.

I am running into some problems as of late. I am learning TypeScript today and I am stuck in the middle of some disastrous predicament. I am trying to install BASH into VS code but I am receiving the following error.

This is the error I receive  -

```
Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.
```

Here's the code I typed into ***"settings.json"***.

The following code does not work.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe",
```

**here's a snippet of my settings.json file**

> 

```js
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula Soft",
  "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
  "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
  "files.exclude": "out": false
  "search.exclude": "out": true 
  "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib" // we want to use the TS server from our node_modules folder to control its version
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's a lot of work. why not install Bash thru Windows. I did, it works fine in VS Code too. You don't need to mess with any config in VS CODE or JSON if you do it this way.

https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

let me know if that helps!